# What is the technical definition of an Optional in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

First off, I understand what an *optional* is and what it does in Swift. However, I noticed the absence of a technical definition for it in the Apple Swift documentation. It defines it as:

> You use optionals in situations where a value may be absent. An optional says:
>
> There is a value, and it equals x
>   or
>
> There isn’t a value at all

So...is *optional* a type? a type declaration? How would you actually define *optional* in one sentence?

Comment: Optional type mean: Can accept `nil` value.

Answer (score 4):

Optional is an `Enum`, which can have two states:

- `.None`
- `.Some(T)`

[Here](http://swiftdoc.org/type/Optional/) are some more information about `Optionals`.

Answer (score 2):

> The Swift language defines the postfix ? as syntactic sugar for the named type Optional, which is defined in the Swift standard library.
>
> The type Optional is an enumeration with two cases, None and Some(T), which are used to represent values that may or may not be present. Any type can be explicitly declared to be (or implicitly converted to) an optional type. If you don’t provide an initial value when you declare an optional variable or property, its value automatically defaults to nil.

[You can find more details in the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)

Comment: Thank you for this :). This makes more sense now. Why the hell don't they put this in the actual documentation. smh.

Comment: @WalterM: The above citation *is from the actual documentation*.